# Add Assembly from SQL Server Database Project with Other DLL dependencies

Tags: sql-server, dependencies, assemblies

I am currently having an issue deploying some assemblies to using Visual Studio 2022. One Assembly is dependent of MySQl.data.dll and I get the error message below

> Error:  SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6503, Level 16, State 12, Line 1 Assembly 'mysql.data, version=8.0.31.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=xxxxx' was not found in the SQL catalog.

When I tried to manually load MySQL.data.dll I get the error message below

> CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'MySQl.data' failed because assembly 'MySQl.data' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So what version of SQL Server are you attempting to deploy to? What version of .NET was the assembly built for? CLR in SQL Server only supports .NET Framework versions and the specific version(s) supported depend on the version of SQL Server.

Comment: Isn't `MySQl.data.dll` for the MySQL database? Not the SQL Server database?

Comment: @DaleK it's a native client for accessing MySQL servers from .NET applications. Version 8.0.31 requires .NET Framework 4.8, so would require SQL Server 2016 or later with .NET Framework 4.8.* installed on the host.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It is SQL Server 2019. .Net 4.8.1